# How to rename a data frame in H2o Flow?

Tags: h2o

Using the h2o interface I am not able to figure out how to rename a data frame previously created.

[image: after get frame command]

I was trying to find a way via: `getFrameSummary` command, but there is no rename option.
[image]

Any workaround?, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to change the frame id from Flow once the data has been parsed.  If you want to change it when you're uploading, then you do that here (see ID field):

[image]

Though that is not helpful if you're talking about renaming frames that were created in the modeling process.  An alternative is to open up R or Python, connect to your H2O cluster, and change it from there using the `h2o.assign()` function (same function name in R/Py).

Comment: Thx, effectively I am looking for renaming it after parsing the file.